# Automation of word using VC++,Com

Tags: visual-c++

I have an application in VC++ 2005.
I need retrieve some status bar information from Word2003,
such as: Page,section,
How I can do it?
Someone have link or sample code in VC++

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with Word using Office automation and COM. See e.g. [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/MSOfficeAuto.aspx) on The Code Project for sample code, and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kw65a0we%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for the Word Object Model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but i cant the page number and the footer of the word document can u help me with that pls